# Having an issue with laravel hasOne relationship returning null

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables `listings` and `saved_listings`. both have a relationship in `saved_listings` `listing_id`
Trying to return an instance of `saved_listings` from `listings` model with `hasOne` relationship but it is returning null.

Listing Model

```
public function savedListing (): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(SavedListing::class);
    }
```

Blade

```
@dump(\App\Models\Listing::find(5)->saved_listing)
```

// returning null, and it has a record

I have even tried adding the `foreign_key` and `local_key` still nothing

```
public function savedListing (): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(SavedListing::class, 'listing_id', 'id');
    }
```

Comment: have you tried via the dynamic property `savedListing`?

Comment: No.. Can you help me on how?

Comment: `->savedListing` instead of `->saved_listing`

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much, never thought about that.

Comment: that is the name of the relationship method, `savedListing`, why were you trying to use the dynamic property `saved_listing`?

Comment: Seriously I can't tell. Thank you, have been on this for hours now.

Comment: good luck, have fun and enjoy Laravel

Answer (score 0):

You can get all data from saved_listings table:

```
public function savedListing (): 
{
  return $this->hasOne(SavedListing::class, 'id', 'listing_id');
}
```

And you can use that relation function name like savedListing->name whatever data you can get.